# Why is Elijah missing from Tozer's "The Saint Must Walk Alone"?

Tags: prophets, elijah, aw-tozer

Tozer's ["The Saint Must Walk Alone"](http://www.worldinvisible.com/library/tozer/5j00.0010/5j00.0010.39.htm) starts with:

> MOST OF THE WORLD'S GREAT SOULS have been lonely. Loneliness seems to be one price the saint must pay for his saintliness.

He then goes on to discuss Enoch, Noah, Abraham, Sarah, Lot, Moses, Christ.

In particular, he states:

> The pain of loneliness arises from the constitution of our nature. God made us for each other. The desire for human companionship is completely natural and right. The loneliness of the Christian results from his walk with God in an ungodly world, a walk that must often take him away from the fellowship of good Christians as well as from that of the unregenerate world. His Godgiven instincts cry out for companionship with others of his kind, others who can understand his longings, his aspirations, his absorption in the love of Christ; and because within his circle of friends there are so few who share his inner experiences he is forced to walk alone. The unsatisfied longings of the prophets for human understanding caused them to cry out in their complaint, and even our Lord Himself suffered in the same way.

Now, if we are to discuss loneliness, it's hard to miss Elijah in 1 Kings 17:

> 1 Kings 17: 2 And the word of the Lord came unto him, saying,
>   3 Get thee hence, and turn thee eastward, and hide thyself by the brook Cherith, that is before Jordan.
>   4 And it shall be, that thou shalt drink of the brook; and I have commanded the ravens to feed thee there.
>   5 So he went and did according unto the word of the Lord: for he went and dwelt by the brook Cherith, that is before Jordan.
>   6 And the ravens brought him bread and flesh in the morning, and bread and flesh in the evening; and he drank of the brook.
>   7 And it came to pass after a while, that the brook dried up, because there had been no rain in the land.

The guy drank from a brook and was fed by ravens for who knows how long!

### Question

Why is Elijah not mentioned in Tozer's essay? Was Elijah not considered a Saint a that time? Did Elijah not walk alone enough? Is there some other reason that sets Elijah's life out from the other examples Tozer cites?

Comment: I have and am still trying to assertsin have Elijah and Moses taken on glorified bodies in heaven. Personally I find this not easy to accept yet many longer serving saints have said yes they have.
I do accept what mr tozer says about walking alone. In many ways it brings me closer to our Father as I spend hours upon hours driving alone with the audio scriptures playing all day long. Such a blessing being alone with the scriptures over these very long hours in travel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tozer does include Elijah he just does not list each name of the prophets.

> The prophets of pre-Christian times differed widely from each other, but one mark they bore in common was their enforced loneliness. They loved their people and gloried in the religion of the fathers, but their loyalty to the God of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob, and their zeal for the welfare of the nation of Israel drove them away from the crowd and into long periods of heaviness. "I am become a stranger unto my brethren, and an alien unto my mother's children," cried one and unwittingly spoke for all the rest. (A. W. Tozer, [The Saint Must Walk Alone](http://www.truthaccordingtoscripture.com/documents/articles/the-saint-must-walk-alone.php))

This is the typical insightful Tozer and an excellent sermon.

Comment: The quote "I am become ..." appears to be from Psalms. Are you saying Elijah is covered under "The prophets of pre-Christian times ..." ?

Comment: @Matthew7.7 - Yes i am saying Tozer would agree with you for all the prophets before Christ in the OT were lonley according to his sermon.